# Is there a good .NET version of DelphiFeeds.com?

Tags: c#, feed, aggregators

Delphifeeds.com aggregates a large number of Delphi-related feeds that include both the official feeds from Embarcadero and independent bloggers from the community. I am looking for a similar thing for .NET and C# in particular. I am aware of course of the official Microsoft feeds, but I can't find a good repository of unaffiliated and technical feeds.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

http://www.dzone.com/links/tag/.net.html

http://www.dotnetkicks.com/default.aspx

http://www.alvinashcraft.com (Dew Drop)

Comment: Dotnetkicks looks a lot like Delphifeeds. Good to have a few options though.

Answer (score 1):

While they aren't all and any feeds for .NET this is better.

http://www.dotnetkicks.com/default.aspx

Why I think this is better is that people have decided that a blog post is worth kicking.  That way it cuts out noise.

I see all the official stuff and more but just subscribing to the [DotNetKicks](http://www.dotnetkicks.com/default.aspx) feed.